# How do I remove access JS object properties with double quotation

Tags: javascript, json, xml, object

I fetch a data from a URL. and the data looks like the code below. How do I access the image source, and  contents? ( Note when I console.log data.description,  it consoled undefined).

```
data:{
 title: "title of the data"
description:"<div class="feed-description"><p style="text-align: center;"><img alt="" src="http://....jpg" style="width: 600px; height: 350px;" /></p><p><government's financial crisis?</p><p>Working out us realling good for your body(<em>depass</em>).</p><p>Finance Ministry insider disclosed that the annual <em>depass</em> at the State House cost.</p></div>"
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the *actual response* verbatim? If so, you should fix the broken API so that it returns proper parsable JSON instead.

Comment: Yes, that's the response I got. It's fetched rss feed URL ( a website).

Comment: Assuming that `data` is actually a real object, can you try `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))`. The console representation of JS objects don't translate well to copy/pasted text

Comment: Even if in use 'JSON.stringify(data)'  i can only console the 'data' not 'data.discription'

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the response is obtained as a constant:

```
const data = {
 title: "title of the data",
 description:`<div class="feed-description"><p style="text-align: center;"><img alt="" src="http://....jpg" style="width: 600px; height: 350px;" /></p><p><government's financial crisis?</p><p>Working out us realling good for your body(<em>depass</em>).</p><p>Finance Ministry insider disclosed that the annual <em>depass</em> at the State House cost.</p></div>`
}
```

If you'll like to access the contents for the description HTML string, you'll need to parse this string creating a dummy DOM element and add the string to it.
Then you can manipulate it like any DOM element.

Example:

```
const el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = data.description;

// Getting the image source
const img = el.getElementsByTagName('img')[0]; // matching the first position
const source = img.src;

// Getting the div content
const divContent = el.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]
```